# Magento - passing params in URL to template file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a template file at `../page/video.phtml` and it's served at `http://mysite/video`.

I want to add params in the url to play different videos on that page. I can add it as a query string param, `http://mysite/video?select=filename` but I would prefer to use `http://mysite/video/filename`.

However, when I try this I get a 404. What would I have to do to achieve this?

I'm using Magento 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly include all the action parts (route, controller and action) in the URL  before adding parameters this way, because when you use `http://mysite/video/filename`, Magento looks for the `index` action of the `filename` controller for the module having a front route named `video` (which does not exist, hence the 404 error).

From the URL you gave, a working URL would rather look like this : `http://mysite/video/index/index/select/filename`